# require to retype username and password after postbackurl to the login.aspx page

Tags: asp.net

How to null the textbox and type new username and password when I click logout, It will go back to the login.aspx and the textbox will be null or will be empty and will require to retype the username and password. What i did: I only change the properties of my button, i use postbackurl to my login.aspx and still the textbox has a current username and password. Please help as soon as possible, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what it is that you want to do so here are two courses of action you can take based on my understanding of your question.

#### Clear username & password fields on the login form after user has logged out

Simply add the following to your Page_Load method on your Login page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtUsername.Text = String.Empty;
    txtPassword.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

This should clear any values input there previously, but I doubt it will make a difference in cases where the login credentials have been saved on the user's browser. In such a case, the browser should input the values anyway as a matter of convenience to the user.

#### Populate username in login form after the user has logged out

When the user logs in, you're probably storing some Session values to keep the user's info available for the pages that need it.

When the user clicks logout, you can create a new Session value before the redirect with the user's Username that you can populate into the username field on the login screen.

As you've not specified which language you're using, I'll assume C#.

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LogoutName = Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]); // gets the username from the user's login session

    Session.Clear();

    Session["LogoutName"] = LogoutName;

    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

On Login.aspx, you'll read the value as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["LogoutName"])))
    {
        txtUsername.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["LogoutName"]);
        Session.Clear();
    }
}
```

You may have to put this into an `if (!IsPostBack)` block but I don't think that should be necessary here.

This will pre-populate the username field on the login form with the username of the user who just logged out. It will not keep it permanently so if the browser window is closed, the session will expire naturally and no value will be loaded into the field.

Hope this helps!